# Filter d3 SVG by JSON Attribute Based on Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, svg

I have node and link data for a force directed graph. Nodes may have one, two, or three links between them:

```
{"nodes": [{"id": "Michael Scott", "numOfLinks": 1}
          ,{"id": "Jim Halpert", "numOfLinks": 1}
          ,{"id": "Pam Beasley", "numOfLinks": 2}
          ,{"id": "Kevin Malone", "numOfLinks": 2}
          ,{"id": "Angela", "numOfLinks": 3}
          ,{"id": "Dwight Schrute", "numOfLinks": 3}]
,"links": [{"source": "Michael Scott", "target": "Jim Halpert", "type": "red"}
          ,{"source": "Pam Beasley", "target": "Kevin Malone", "type": "red"}
          ,{"source": "Pam Beasley", "target": "Kevin Malone", "type": "white"}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "type": "red"}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "type": "white"}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "type": "blue"}]
}
```

I have an HTML drop down for users to filter out nodes (and corresponding links) that don't have a certain number of links:

```
<select id="selectLinkNumber" name="selectLinkNumber">
     <option value="1">All</option>
     <option value="2">Two or More Links</option>
     <option value="3">Three or More Links</option>
</select>
```

I have incorporated this drop down into my d3 code:

```
var dropdown = d3.select("#selectLinkNumber")
var change = function() {
d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove()
var val = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;

d3.json("test.json", function(error, graph) {
    //do stuff
    })
}
dropdown.on("change", change)
change();
```

This results in a graph that is removed and reappears when a new selection is made from the drop down. The goal is to have only the nodes with values greater than or equal to the selection appear. For example, if "Three" is chosen, only Angela, Dwight, and their three links appear. If "Two" is chosen, Pam, Kevin, Angela, Dwight, and their corresponding links are chosen.

Logically, I think there needs to be something that filters the `test.json` data directly after the `d3.json("test.json", function(error, graph) {` line, based on `val`. I'm not sure how to efficiently accomplish this however. This example (https://jsfiddle.net/tgv6s5cd/14/) essentially does what I'm looking for, but I couldn't figure my way past the manual data creation and numerous functions. I think it would be simpler to just filter once after bringing in `test.json`

How should I filter data once the user makes a dropdown selection?

Answer (score 0):

That is basic array manipulation in Javascript. `graph` after all is just an object with two array properties.

```
d3.json("test.json", function(error, graph) {
    var filteredNodes = graph.nodes.filter(d => d.numOfLinks >= val);
    var names = filteredNodes.map(d => d.id);
    var filteredLinks = graph.links.filter((d) => {
        return (names.indexOf(d.source) >= 0) || 
               (names.indexOf(d.target) >= 0)
    });

    var filteredGraph = {
        nodes: filteredNodes,
        links: filteredLinks
    };
    // render
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How would that code change if `value` was in the links array?

Comment: I changed the first line to `var filteredLinks = graph.links.filter(d => d.numOfLinks >= val);`, and I belive the `var filteredGraph` would stay the same. Just not sure how to map back to the nodes since they only have `id` and not `source` and `target`.